# VBA write to text file: Run-time error 52 'bad file name or number'

Tags: vba

```
Public Sub EdgeColor_Click()
    Dim intInFile As Integer
    intInFile = FreeFile

    Open "c:\picturename.csv" For Output As #intFileNo
    Print #intFileNo, "test"

    Close #intFileNo
End Sub
```

This is my code, and I get Run-time error 52 'bad file name or number'. I've tried doing as Input and making the file exist but I get the same error.

This is VBA inside of a Proficy iFix graphic, and can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mixing up `intInFile` and `intFileNo`.

It's possible that `intFileNo` is simply set to zero if you're not using the `option explicit` command, which may explain the invalid number.

That little command goes at the top of *every one* of my VB/VBA files because I've been burnt by this so many time before.

Comment: Wow I am completely retarded, I have no idea how I didn't realise that.

Also I didn't know you could use option explicit in VBA, thank you so much.

:)

Comment: @rolls, you can also go to `Tools` - `Options...` - `Editor` tab - then check `Require Variable Declaration` to have Option Explicit turned on by default for all new modules.